# Counting the number of uploaded files

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I am working on my CodeIgniter project, and it is so far working very well.

However, I need some way to count the number of uploaded files, since I want to limit it in some cases (but not all).

How can I do that? I tried `count($_FILES)` but that gave me nothing usable.

I also tried a bunch of other things, but neither gave me the information I need.

The upload form is a multiple file upload, and I am using [this](https://github.com/stvnthomas/CodeIgniter-2.1-Multi-Upload) library to handle multiple uploads.

The upload function without the counting looks like this:

```
function do_upload()
{
    $setid = $this->input->post('imageset');
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        $this->upload->initialize(array(
                "upload_path"   => "./photos/",
                "allowed_types" => "jpg|jpeg|png|gif",
                "encrypt_name" => TRUE
        ));
        try {
            $this->upload->do_multi_upload("files");
            $images = $this->upload->get_multi_upload_data();
            $config = array(
                    'image_library'  => 'gd2',
                    'create_thumb'   => TRUE,
                    'maintain_ratio' => TRUE,
                    'width'          => '145',
                    'height'         => '145'
            );
            foreach ($images as $image)
            {
                $config['source_image'] = $image['full_path'];
                $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
                $this->image_lib->resize();
                $this->manage_model->insertimage($image['file_name'],$image['orig_name'],$image['file_size'],$image['file_type'],$setid);
            }
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Billederne er nu blevet uploadet.');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $e);
        }
        redirect('manage/images','refresh');
}
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: `count($images)` after you set that variable.

Comment: @jeroen: The problem is that if I count the images via the `$images` variable, and then throw an error, the images has already been uploaded to the server, and I want to do the counting before that happens.

Comment: If you want to avoid the upload, you need to do it client-side using javascript (perhaps in combination with php using ajax).

Comment: @jeroen:  I don't neccessarily want to avoid the upload part - as long as the images stay in the tmp folder, and not in the upload_path.

Comment: @crypticツ because that gives me 1 no matter how many files that are being uploaded. Might have something to do with the multi-multi-dimensional array PHP uses for such things.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check the number of items in your `$_FILES` variable using for example:

```
$total = count($_FILES['your_variable_array_in_html']['tmp_name']);
```

You need to do that before the:

```
$this->upload->do_multi_upload("files");
```

line.

As you have already noticed, `$_FILES` only contains one variable - an array - containing arrays of the different sections, `tmp_name`, `name`, `error`, etc. Check the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) for more details.

Comment: @jeroen Any idea how to get the count of the number of files a user has actually uploaded. Right now, my form has `5` file fields, and using this method gives me `5` even when the user uploads only `2` files.

Comment: `count` shows always `1 ` And some Time It shows 5 when i upload file

Answer (score 1):

if you want to limit the files uploaded.
you may limit them in two steps:

1. Only accept a specified array name of the uploading files. i.e files[]
2. Now you can easily count the files uploaded by

> count($_FILES['files']['name']);

string 'name' can be replaced by 'tmp_name', 'error', 'size', 'type'

The library that you used have uploaded files into your upload path when it is first executed. so you should manually check it before you do upload.

```php
  function do_upload()
  {
    $setid = $this->input->post('imageset');
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $this->upload->initialize(array(
        "upload_path"   => "./photos/",
        "allowed_types" => "jpg|jpeg|png|gif",
        "encrypt_name" => TRUE
    ));
    if (isset($_FILES['files']['name'])) {
      $num = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
    }

        try {
          $this->upload->do_multi_upload("files");
          $images = $this->upload->get_multi_upload_data();
          $config = array(
              'image_library'  => 'gd2',
              'create_thumb'   => TRUE,
              'maintain_ratio' => TRUE,
              'width'          => '145',
              'height'         => '145'
          );
          foreach ($images as $image)
          {
            $config['source_image'] = $image['full_path'];
            $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
            $this->image_lib->resize();
            $this->manage_model->insertimage($image['file_name'],$image['orig_name'],$image['file_size'],$image['file_type'],$setid);
          }
          $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Billederne er nu blevet uploadet.');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
          $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $e);
        }
        redirect('manage/images','refresh');
      }
```

hope this helps

Comment: I could be wrong but count() will always return a value of 1 or more unless the paramter is NULL in which case it returns 0 so if no files are uploaded the value of count() is still 1