# how to count files from input field in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to collect number of selected files. My html is like--

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="file" class="img" name="userfile[]"  > 
<input type="file" id="file" class="img" name="userfile[]"  >
<button type="submit"  name="add">Add</button>
</form>
```

In my controller i used

> $cp= count($_FILES['userfile']['name']); echo $cp;

which print value 2.. even if i don't select any file.
how do i get the correct value from my selected file field??

N.B: i can select 0 to 2 number of files

Comment: Try with $cp= count($_FILES) once

Comment: it's showing >>1<< when i am selecting no file

Comment: check the link, it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501913/counting-the-number-of-uploaded-files

Answer (score 0):

First do the:

```
$this->upload->do_multi_upload("files");
```

Then your filecount is:

```
count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_filter()`

```
$cp= count(array_filter($_FILES['userfile']['name'])); 
echo $cp;
```

If you not selected any file it keeps null in `$_FILES['userfile']['name']` so `array_filter()` removes blank elements from array and you can get exact count of selected files.